# CDI injection in recursive structure

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Suppose I have two real implementations A and B of some interface. And there is also a Delegate-implemenation of that interface that delegates to either A or B dependending on some logic.

I want to have the Delegate injected into my client class so I marked A and B as @Alternatives to make that unambiguous. However, now the injection into the Delegate does not work since A and B are alternatives.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
import org.jglue.cdiunit.AdditionalClasses;
import org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Alternative;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses({ CdiTest.A.class, CdiTest.B.class, CdiTest.Delegate.class })
public class CdiTest {

    public interface Service {
        void run();
    }

    @Alternative
    public static class A implements CdiTest.Service {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hi from A");
        }
    }

    @Alternative
    public static class B implements CdiTest.Service {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hi from B");
        }
    }

    public static class Delegate implements CdiTest.Service {
        int counter = 0;
        @Inject A a;
        @Inject B b;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hi from Delegate");
            if ((counter++) % 2 == 0) a.run();
            else b.run();
        }
    }

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        service.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try with qualifiers or maybe a producer method along with `Instance<Service>` to get rid of the delegate (or convert the delegate into the producer). You might also want to provide some scope information to your implementations as not to use dependent scope.

Comment: That would resolve the dependency only once. Suppose I need to decide on each call which implementation to use.

Comment: That's why I suggested using `Instance<Service>`, e.g. by calling `select(...)` in your test code to select which implementation you want to use for a certain call.

Comment: You mean like using `serviceInstance.select(Delegate.class).get().run();` in the client code?
That would tie the client code to the Delegate-Instance and how could I swap that out for testing?

Comment: No I mean something like `serviceInstance.select( (counter % 2 == 0) ? A.class : B.class).get().run();`. Besides that, isn't the selection/delegate part of your test code only?

Comment: No, the selection part is for production runtime. Roughly, some request parameter can select the demo data service.

I don't want to put the selection logic inside the client. For tests it should not be active but rather some service, say A should always be used.

Comment: In that case couldn't `Delegate` be the only implementation of `Service` and internally directly use `A` and `B`? Then for your tests configure the condition in a way that alway the same of the two is selected.

Comment: Yes, that's a possible solution. One thing that would need is to make the selector configurable. But changing the interfaces is something I really don't want to do. From a code design perspective I think that A and B SHOULD implement that interface.

I am reluctant to worsen the code to make DI work. I think the structure is ok as it is.

But I guess CDI is not as flexible as I had hoped.

Comment: The only real switch coming from CDI to swap out dependencies is this Alternatives concept. So I could add yet another interface and have the Delegate implement that and A. Also make A an alternative which I just activate in my tests. But having an additional interface with no real meaning except to mark the intended implemenations for the client really sounds like bad design to me.

Comment: I used Guice in other projects and I think it would be trivial to solve the problem using that. In the produciton Module I would bind `Service` to `Delegate` and in the tests module I would bind it to `A`. Done.
No additional interfaces or annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I think tha you need qualifiers instead of alternatives.

Have you tried using two qualifiers `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`? You could inject in the delegate both implementations and in real test the delegate.

**EDIT**

I don't think you should replace the delegate with a producer (from your example I understood that the delegate has some functional role in your application and is not only a
test/production switch).
I think that you could create another class with a producer method like this:

```
public class ServiceProducer {

    private static final String SERVICE_A = "service-a";
    private static final String SERVICE_B = "service-a";
    private static final String SERVICE_DELEGATE = "service-delegate";

    @Produces
    @Chosen
    public CdiTest.Service getService(@SystemProperty("service.choose.key") String chosenKey,
            @ServiceA Instance<Service> a, 
            @ServiceB Instance<Service> b, 
            @ServiceDelegate Instance<Service> delegate) {

        switch(chosenKey) {
            case SERVICE_A:
                return a.get();
            case SERVICE_B:
                return b.get();
            case SERVICE_DELEGATE:
                return delegate.get();
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("No Service implementation for type " + chosenKey);
        }
    }

}
```

The @SystemProperty is a useful solution to inject system properties found at http://juraj.blahunka.eu/2014/05/17/inject-jboss-system-properties/

So you example code could be changed in:

```
public class CdiTest {

    public interface Service {
        void run();
    }

    @ServiceA
    public static class A implements CdiTest.Service {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hi from A");
        }
    }

    @ServiceB
    public static class B implements CdiTest.Service {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hi from B");
        }
    }


    @ServiceDelegate
    public static class Delegate implements CdiTest.Service {
        int counter = 0;
        @Inject @ServiceA Service a;
        @Inject @ServiceB Service b;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hi from Delegate");
            if ((counter++) % 2 == 0) a.run();
            else b.run();
        }
    }

    @Inject
    @Chosen
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        service.run();
    }
}
```

This way you inject implementations A and B inside the delegate (without using the producer) and the produced one in your test class (choosing the correct implementation with a system property named "service.choose.key").

Comment: So I would need 3 Qualifiers, right? Another one for Delegate.

Comment: However, if i put the Delegate Qualifier on the clients dependecy - how can I swap that one out when I am testing?!

Comment: you can use just 2 qualifiers because the delegate class could use `@Default` that is always associated with beans.

Comment: Ok, that should work.
Yet, how would I swap out the implementation out for testing. Say I want to always have A injected for tests (instead of the delegate).

Comment: I'm sorry but i do not understand very clearly your problem. You want to test separately single implementations and the delegate? Why don't you create 3 test units? Or inject each implementation and use them?

Comment: Let me rephrase my requirement:

The client class should depend only on the interface `Service` which should resolve to `Delegate` in production and to `A` for tests.

Comment: Could you use a configuration flag stored somewhere? File, database, system property?

Comment: And then make the client pick an implementation based on that? Like `return isProd() ? delegateService : serviceA;` That logic should not be in the client! I think that's the DI framework's job. CDI's approach for such switches is the alternatives concept which is too limited for this case as far as I can see it.

Comment: Not the client but a CDI producer. It can choose which implementation inject based on your flag. Does not it fit your needs?

Comment: How would exchanging the delegate-class with a Producer instance/class solve the problem? I still can't swap out the implementation for the tests. Also do note that its not sufficient to resolve between A and B only once (which I guess a Provider would do). In my real code, it is dependent on some method parameter supplied to the delegate-method.